# Record voice and save it to mp3 file

Tags: actionscript-3, record, voice

Is it possible to record (5 seconds) a voice with the microphone and save it as a mp3 file WITHOUT sending data to the server? I would like to save the file with FileReference (some times ago I did an experiment saving a bitmap and it worked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MicRecorder](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858) class for recording the sound, and [as3lameencoder](http://code.google.com/p/as3lameencoder/) for encoding the recorded byte stream into mp3.